# How to list files in remote repository, without cloning?

Tags: c#, .net, libgit2sharp

Is there a way to use [LibGit2Sharp](http://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp) to get a list of the files in a **remote repository**, but **without cloning** the repository locally?

I'd like to **list the files**, but also **get the content of the files**.

```
var files = GetGithubFiles(); // TODO: Implement
foreach(var file in files)
{
    Console.WriteLine(file.Title);
    Console.WriteLine(file.Content);
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way to use LibGit2Sharp to get a list of the files in a remote repository, but without cloning the repository locally?

There's no currently built-in mechanism to perform such task.

Beside retrieving the list of files of the commits of each heads of the repository, cloning fetches the whole history. This may indeed take some time.

However, below some alternative to help you forward:

- Leverage now the **[GitHub API](http://developer.github.com/v3/)**
- Wait for the future support of **[shallow clones](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/issues/229)**, which should allow you to retrieve a shorter version of the history, perform your analysis and eventually discard the temporary repository.

Comment: Is this still not possible using LibGit2Sharp? You answered the question on 2012 Dec, just curious to know if this is possible in the newer versions.

Comment: Sadly, shallow cloning isn't supported yet.

Comment: Is there any other way to get the files from a TFS repository without cloning. My code is hosted on a TFS server which uses GIT version control. This is not in GitHub.

Comment: @SKJ For Visual Studio Online you can use Infinity.NET: https://github.com/ethomson/infinity.net

Comment: @EdwardThomson Thanks for the link. I tried to use VSO Rest API but was facing few issues. I hope using this .NET API, I will be able to get the data properly.